# Analysis: Determine radius and interval of convergence for these power series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

I needed to determine the radius and interval of convergence for each of the following;

$\mathbb{One:}$ $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{3^nx^n}{n!}$$

$\mathbb{Two:}$ $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{(1+n^2)}$$

$\mathbb{Three:}$ $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}(x+1)^n}{n}$$

Comment: Is $\mathbb{This}$ the effect you wanted, or were you trying to do something like **This** (`**This**`)?

Comment: @omnomnomnom, That's the effect I wanted :) I'm using this to help revise for my exams

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\mathbb{One:}$ Radius of convergence is $\infty$, interval of convergence is $\mathbb{R}$. Apply the ratio test and calculate:

$$\lim_{{n}\rightarrow{\infty}}\left | \frac{3^{n+1}x^{n+1}/(n+1)!}{3^nx^n/n!}\right|=|x|\space \lim_{{n}\rightarrow{\infty}}\frac{3}{n+1}=0$$

Hence, this series converges absolutely for all values of $x$ (since this limit is $0$ for every value of $x$.

$\mathbb{Two:}$ Radius of convergence is $1$, interval of convergence is $[-1,1]$. Apply the ratio test and calculate:

$$\lim_{{n}\rightarrow{\infty}}\left | \frac{x^{n+1}/(1+(n+1)^2)}{x^n/(1+n^2)}\right|=|x|\space \lim_{{n}\rightarrow{\infty}}\frac{1+n^2}{2+2n+n^2}=\left | x \right |.$$

Hence, this series converges absolutely for $\left | x \right |<1$, and so the radius of converge is $1$. We now need to check the endpoints of the interval $(-1,1)$:

At $x=-1$, the series becomes $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{1+n^2}$, which converges absolutely.

At $x=1$, the series becomes $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+n^2}$, which converges absolutely.

So, the series converges absolutely for all $x$ in the closed interval $[-1,1]$, and diverges elsewhere.

$\mathbb{Three:}$ Radius of convergence is $1$, interval of convergence is $(−2,0]$. Apply the ratio test and calculate:

$$\lim_{{n}\rightarrow{\infty}}\left | \frac{(-1)^{(n+1)+1}(x+1)^{n+1}/(n+1)}{(-1)^{n+1}(x+1)^n/n}\right|=|x+1|\space \lim_{{n}\rightarrow{\infty}}\frac{n}{n+1}=\left | x +1\right |.$$

Hence, this series converges absolutely for $|x + 1| < 1$, and so the radius of convergence is $1$. We now need to check the endpoints of the interval $(−2, 0)$:

At $x = −2$, the series becomes  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}(-1)^n}{n}=-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}$, which diverges, being a constant multiple of the harmonic series.

At $x = 0$, the series becomes $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}$, which converges conditionally, as it is the alternating harmonic series.

So, the series converges absolutely for all x in the open interval $(−2, 0)$, converges conditionally at $x = 0$, and diverges elsewhere.